# Check OID size in table

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1, postgresql-9.3

I want to check the actual size of a OID object in PostgreSQL. In PgAdmin I can see only number. How I can display the actual size?

[image]

Comment: An OID is always 4 bytes, but I'm not sure whether that is what you are asking.

Comment: you're referring the value from the table or?

Comment: Well, an OID is just a 4-byte number. There isn't anything else to it. Or you need to be more specific.

Comment: Ok, for example if I have table with OID object how I can get the size?

Comment: Depends on what kind of object you are talking about.

Comment: I need for bytea and for OID.

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
select octet_length(lo_get(file)) from your_table
```